# Most efficient way to generate day by day sums in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm working on a management system which has several components, one of which is management of physical parts.

In SQL I have a table of part transfers, stating where they're going, where they came from, and the date the transfer took place. Related to that is a table for each of those transfers, with an entry for each part that was transferred within it, along with the amount. Those parts are joined to a separate table indicating their type.

I'm trying to build a report that shows: for each day since the first part transfer, what is the amount of each part type currently in each location on that day. I have some SQL that runs nicely on our newer sites, but for our longer running sites (2017) it takes forever as there is just so many parts/locations/days.

Is trying to optimize this such that it runs on huge amounts of data a fool's errand? I'm looking for the best way to go forward on this, whether that be starting to build out some sort of record cache, or if there's something I'm missing in terms of the most efficient way to calculate this.

For reference, here are some counts pulled from our largest site:

| Data | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Locations | 20496 |
| Part Types | 224 |
| Days | 1176 |

Here's most of the relevant SQL, I did clear some sections out for clarity but if there's something missing, let me know and I'll add it back in.

```sql
SELECT @earliestTransaction = min(actual_date) from partlist
WHERE (partlist.item_type = 'scaffold'
 AND partlist.partlist_type_id = 15)
 OR partlist.partlist_type_id = 6

SELECT @today = (select cast(getdate() as Date))

INSERT INTO @relevantScaffolds
SELECT s.id 
from scaffold s
join sitearea wa on wa.id = s.sitearea_id
where s.project_id = @ProjectID
AND (
(@siteAreaID IS NULL AND @scaffoldID IS NULL)
OR (@siteAreaID IS NOT NULL AND wa.parent_sitearea_id = @siteAreaID)
OR (@scaffoldID IS NOT NULL AND s.id = @scaffoldID)
)

WITH DateTable AS
(
    SELECT @earliestTransaction AS [DATE]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE])
    FROM DateTable
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [DATE]) <= @today
) 

--Get Date collection for all parts
INSERT INTO @datesAndParts
select DISTINCT
 dt.DATE,
 pc.id,
 rs.scaffold_id
from DateTable dt
join part_catalog pc on 1=1
join @relevantScaffolds rs on 1=1
--Remove limit for date recurison
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0)

WITH scaffold_transactions(part_catalog_id, quantity, actual_date, project_id, scaffold_id) AS
(
 -- Into Scaffold 
 SELECT part_catalog_id, sum(quantity),
  partlist.actual_date, partlist.project_id, rs.scaffold_id
 FROM partlist
  INNER JOIN partlist_part on partlist_part.partlist_id = partlist.id
  left join partlist parent on parent.id = partlist.parent_partlist_id
  join part_catalog on part_catalog.id = partlist_part.part_catalog_id
  join @relevantScaffolds rs on rs.scaffold_id = partlist.item_id
 WHERE partlist.item_type = 'scaffold'
 AND partlist.partlist_type_id = 15
 AND partlist.project_id = @ProjectID
 GROUP BY part_catalog_id, partlist.actual_date, partlist.project_id, rs.scaffold_id
 
 UNION ALL
 -- deliveries_to_scaffold 
 SELECT part_catalog_id, SUM(quantity),
  partlist.actual_date, partlist.project_id, rs.scaffold_id
 FROM partlist
  INNER JOIN workorder on workorder.id = partlist.item_id
  join @relevantScaffolds rs on rs.scaffold_id = workorder.scaffold_id
  INNER JOIN partlist_part on partlist_part.partlist_id = partlist.id
  left join partlist parent on parent.id = partlist.partsource_partlist_id
  join part_catalog on part_catalog.id = partlist_part.part_catalog_id

 WHERE partlist.partlist_type_id = 6
 AND partlist.project_id = @ProjectID
 GROUP BY part_catalog_id, partlist.actual_date, partlist.project_id, rs.scaffold_id

 UNION ALL
 -- leaving_scaffold (negated quantities)
 SELECT part_catalog_id, -SUM(quantity),
  transferPartlist.actual_date, transferPartlist.project_id, rs.scaffold_id
 FROM partlist transferPartlist
  INNER JOIN partlist scaffoldPartlist on scaffoldPartlist.id = transferPartlist.parent_partlist_id
  INNER JOIN partlist_part on partlist_part.partlist_id = transferPartlist.id
  join part_catalog on part_catalog.id = partlist_part.part_catalog_id
  join @relevantScaffolds rs on rs.scaffold_id = scaffoldPartlist.item_id
 WHERE transferPartlist.partlist_type_id = 15
 AND scaffoldpartlist.partlist_type_id = 9
 AND scaffoldpartlist.project_id = @ProjectID
 GROUP BY part_catalog_id, transferPartlist.actual_date, transferPartlist.project_id, rs.scaffold_id
)
INSERT INTO @keyedTransfers
select part_catalog_id, SUM(quantity), actual_date, project_id, scaffold_id from scaffold_transactions
group by  part_catalog_id, actual_date, project_id, scaffold_id

INSERT INTO @cleanupTable
select 
dap.date as date,
dap.part_catalog_id,
dap.scaffold_id,
COALESCE(SUM(quantity) over (partition by dap.part_catalog_id, dap.scaffold_id order by dap.date ), 0) as balance
from @datesAndParts dap
left join @keyedTransfers kt on kt.actual_date = dap.date and kt.part_catalog_id = dap.part_catalog_id and kt.scaffold_id = dap.scaffold_id

select date, pc.part_number, pc.description, scaffold.tag, balance
from @cleanupTable ct
join part_catalog pc on pc.id = ct.part_catalog_id
join scaffold on scaffold.id = ct.scaffold_id
where date >= @earliestTransaction AND date <= @today
and balance > 0
order by date, part_number
```

[Here's a link to the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H19I6bob_) while running on one of the successful sites. We have a gap between different sites where they're all quite small or large with no in between, so this dataset is significantly smaller.

Comment: Which part of the batch is slow, the insert into variable or the final query? Have you tried using temp tables instead of table variables? Have you tried merging the two queries together without inserting to table variable? Please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com also [edit] to include full table and index definitions

Comment: Use of a table variable can be a big problem. Suggest you change that to a temp table with appropriate index and try that. But yes - you need to examine plan to understand where your issues are.

Comment: Inside your last CTE in the "deliveries to location" section, you outer join to (alias) parent but never refer to it in the query. Why?

Comment: @Charlieface I added the execution plan from a smaller site. Is there a way to get the execution plan for a SQL query that hasn't finished? If so I can add the plan for one of the large failing sites. pastetheplan.com wasn't working for me so I had to use another one, hopefully that's ok. I also updated the SQL to be the full set, trying to pair it down for readability was likely a mistake on my part.

Comment: @SMor The CTE extra join was because I was trying to simplify the SQL to where I thought the slowdown was likely to be. I've added the full SQL as is now.

Comment: Out of the 380k rows you insert into `@cleanupTable` you only select back 5200. I think you need to filter the insert better. Also, your indexing isn't great as you've got quite a few Index Spools, Table Scans and Clustered Scans on the inner side of loop joins, some of your table variables have no indexing at all. I feel switching to temp tables and/or merging some of the queries together may get better results.

Comment: You probably know that if you run this in SSMS with "Show Actual Execution Plan" enabled, the execution plans for each query will recommend indexes. It might make sense to add at least some of those indexes ( if you haven't already).